# How to get selected row values of extjs grid

Tags: extjs

Hello how can i get values from this object [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKvpl.png) and push them into an empty array this is the code. I don't want to use path may be there is there a function to get them or another code Thx

```
var selectedRowIndexes = [];
        // returns an array of selected records
        var selectedBanners = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(); 
        console.log(selectedBanners);
        Ext.iterate(selectedBanners, function(banner, data) {
            // push the row indexes into your array
        selectedRowIndexes.push(grid.getStore().indexOf(banner)); 
        });
```

Comment: You mean for example you want email value from data object and so on for other 4 attributes? Can you please clearly explain ?

Comment: yes if select both rows and click approve i want to create an array with objects that contain email nume prenume  and so on

Comment: for ex array = [{nume:"Sendrea", prenume:"gheorghe"...}, {nume:"dima"...}] something like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getSelection` gives you an array of selected records.

For each record, you can extract a field using:

`record.get('theField');`